# tag synonym [ext] -> [extjs]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I came across [ext](/questions/tagged/ext) and had to do a bit of research to discover that it's a JavaScript framework, with most of its questions tagged [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs). I tried to propose it as a synonym but discovered that there was a rep requirement *within* the affected tags. What's the right thing to do then?

There are about 100 questions in [ext](/questions/tagged/ext). I went through them all and retagged 3 or 4 that turned out to be about Linux file systems. The rest are unambiguously about the JS library. There are few enough that one *could* retag them all manually, and I started to do so, but then thought that such mass editing might be Frowned Upon, given that even *suggesting* it is something I'm apparently not trusted to without being knowledgeable enough to answer questions about the stuff.

Please advise. Should I undo my retagging edits?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good idea to me.  If you ignore questions with [java](/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), and [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs), [there are 28 questions remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ext+-java+-javascript+-extjs), two of which:

- <strike>[How to get a Dir for .ext of Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6618446/317773)</strike>
- [firefox extension saving in preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5243805/317773)

I was unsure about, but @Henning Makholm has already updated them, Thanks! -- see the comments below.

Comment: The first one I honestly missed. The latter contains javascript code and no obvious indications of another meaning for `ext`. But I probably shouldn't have called that one "unambiguous" :-)

Comment: Hehe.  No worries!  I stared at the 'code' in both.  I couldn't decipher the first question's code.  The second *looks like* Javascript (to a guy who doesn't use Javascript), but I think the OP intended the tag to mean extension?  (as in add-on for Firefox?)  But I am really unsure, so I left them both alone.

Comment: (Smacks forehead). Yes, of course "extension".